# How do you enable the "Designing" tick box in sitecore Experience Editor?

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm looking though the documentation on sitecore for [Personalisation of components](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/walkthrough_personalizing_components). Pretty much the first step is:

> In the Experience Editor, click the View tab and in the Enable group,
>   select **Designing** to enable the design functionality.

Looking at my experience editor though this is greyed out and unclickable:

[image]

I'm logged in as admin and should have full edit rights on this item. I've trawled though the sitecore docs and forums for this issue but I can't see anything that would do this or any fixes. Can anyone advise? I would guess there is some magic rune in the XML config that needs updating but this seems to be an "undocumented feature"...

My site is configured thus:

```xml
<site name="siteName" 
            virtualFolder="/" 
            physicalFolder="/" 
            rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
            startItem="/start-item" 
            database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" 
            registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
            enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" 
            enableAnalytics="true"
            cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" 
            itemwebapi.mode="Off" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"/>
```

I'm using sitecore 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much experimentation (thanks to help from @Marek), I noticed that the `ToggleDesignCapability` command was never getting hit.

I'd seen this answer on the [SC forums](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/701)

> I ran into the same issue when working through an upgrade from 7.5 to
>   8 Update 2. I started doing a compare of my web.config to a stock 8
>   update 2 config, and noticed that the "website" site entry was
>   missing. One would think that it wouldn't be necessary, but when I
>   added it back, the issue was resolved. Here is the line to check for:
>
> ```
> <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" 
> rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" 
> allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" 
> viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" 
> enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" 
> disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
> renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" />
> ```

I'd dismissed it as I already had a site set up as configured, see my question. What I'd missed though (and what wasn't explained in the forum answer) is that you **must explicitly have a site named *website***. If you have a site named something else **this does not work**. We added the above below our existing site configuration, i.e.:

```xml
<site name="siteName" 
            virtualFolder="/" 
            physicalFolder="/" 
            rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
            startItem="/start-item" 
            database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" 
            registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
            enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" 
            enableAnalytics="true"
            cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" 
            itemwebapi.mode="Off" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"/>

<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" 
    allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" 
    viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" 
    enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" 
    disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
    renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" />
```

The buttons are now enabled as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If your user has Administrator rights, there are 3 scenarios when the checkbox can be disabled:

1. Page is marked as `read only` - go to Content Editor and check the `Appearance` section. There should be `Read only` checkbox.
2. You are in Experience Editor, but in Preview mode. Check the ribbon in Experience Editor - first section should be `Mode`. Make sure that `Edit` option is selected.
3. Your user has set `Deny` for `Write` access right for that item.

From what I remember, in some Sitecore versions `Designing` was disabled also when some other user locked the item, but it should not be like that in Sitecore 8 anymore. Anyway, you may want to check it the page is not locked.

[image]

Still not working? Try to use the code below. Checkbox should be enabled all the time now. Uncomment original code and debug to see why it's not enabled for your user:

```cs
namespace MyAssembly.Namespace
{
  [Serializable]
  public class ToggleDesignCapability : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.ToggleDesignCapability
  {
    public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
    {
      return CommandState.Enabled;

      /*
          //Original QueryState code - remove return statement above and uncomment to debug

          CommandState commandState = base.QueryState(context);
          Item obj = context.Items.Length > 0 ? context.Items[0] : (Item) null;
          if (obj != null && (commandState == CommandState.Enabled || commandState == CommandState.Down) && !WebEditCommand.CanDesignItem(obj))
            return CommandState.Disabled;
          return commandState;
      */
    }
  }
}
```

And replace original command type in `App_config/Include/Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config` for `webedit:toggledesigncapability` command with:

```
  <command name="webedit:toggledesigncapability" type="MyAssembly.Namespace.ToggleDesignCapability, MyAssembly" />
```

Comment: 2 and 3 seems fine, I'm in Edit mode and admin is not "deny" on write access. Looking at 1 though, when looking at the item my Configure -> apperance tab does not have a "Read only" tick box. I'll add a creen shot into the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: Checkbox is in the Content Editor, not in Experience Editor. See screenshot in the answer

Comment: What dll is that pipeline in? I seem to be missing a reference, `WebEdit` is not a namespace under `Sitecore.Shell.Applications` in my solution

Comment: Ah, found it `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems it was a configuration issue. The above code was never getting hit which lead me to the answer below.